launch.substitutions.LaunchDescriptionArgument not implemented in ROS2 Jazzy
I was trying to use launch.substitutions.LaunchDescriptionArgument in my my_launch.launch.py file, but it seems that it is not implemented.
From https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/p/launch/architecture.html#substitutions:

launch.substitutions.LaunchDescriptionArgument: this substitution gets the value of a launch description argument, as a string, by name.

By looking at the source code (https://github.com/ros2/launch/tree/jazzy/launch/launch/substitutions), there is no reference to that substitution.
Am I misinterpreting the documentation? Or should I open an issue?
Thanks.

I don't think you're misinterpreting the documentation, I ran git blame and as early as #88ae20ee when the architecture doc is written, that substitution didn't exist 6 years ago. The repo even at that point suggests the availability of the substitution in the docs. I think its remained in the docs out of inertia. A very useful substitution though, and worth implementing imo.
